# Should i use mongodb for large file storage in MEAN apps?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I want to build a document management system in MEAN (MongoDB,Express,Angular and Node).
It will be used to store large document file(approx. 100 MB), image etc.
Where should i keep the uploaded files in my app, filesystem or MongoDB. Can anybody help?

Comment: That heavily depends on a lot of factors, such as needs in scalability, your deployment scenario and alike. Please elaborate your question accordingly and post it on http://dba.stackexchange.com, since stackoverflow is dedicated to programming questions. I will happily answer it there, if you add the mentioned details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `Gridfs` feature of mongodb for file management.
It uses streams and doesn't take lots of memory for file handling.
And if you are gonna use these document with your other collections in your database, I recommend store file in `Gridfs` => http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/